# Codeigniter callback function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am facing this problem from yesterday and can not fix it. My callback function is not working. It's always returning TRUE, but i don't know why? Can anyone help me?

Here is the the model:

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model {
public function check_login($str)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_login', 'Error');
        return FALSE;

    }
function validate_login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'callback_check_login');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}}
```

The callback function should never return TRUE. But it's returning! I am going to die with this problem! :@

Comment: why is your `validate_login` method returning booleans and not loading views or setting output? How do you conclude that the `check_login` method always return true (which is impossible as the doesn't return true). We need more code and more explanation, since this shouldn't be working for anything in CI at all.

Comment: Shouldn't the data validation go into the controller in CI? Does it even work in model?

Comment: you are right! The callback function does not work in model. I moved the form validation and callback function to the controller and it worked perfectly! @Struna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will return `TRUE` because

1. You are not passing `email` and `password` to 'validate_login()'.
2. So `$this->form_validation->run()` will not work.

move `validate_login()` to any controller

Comment: Thank you, I just moved the code to controller and finally it works! Unbelievable!!!